# how get files under `open editors` Tree View (in other words, opened files) using `vscode extension` APIs?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

This question is quite simple. Although since I just now started exploring vscode extension docs, I couldn't find any solution for this. Basically, I want to  get files under `open editors` Tree View (in other words, opened files) using `vscode extension` APIs.

Thanks

Comment: I am looking for same . Were you able to get the solution?

Comment: I think at that time there was no direct api for this. But someone in vscode forum (in gitter I think) proposed a hacky solution. I'm not sure if they've added the feature currently though